# DynamoDB table creation is too slow

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am doing some scalability testing for one of my programs. As part of this I have to insert millions of records into a dynamodb table take measurements and then rerun the test with different parameters. I need to start with an empty table for each run. Deleting each record from the table takes too much time and so I am deleting the table and recreating it. The table has a GSI which I am creating before each run and after I have set auto-scaling properties on that table it takes upto 1 hour in order for the table to be ready. What could be going wrong?

Comment: What are you putting for the capacity mode? provisioned or on-demand? If provisioned, how many RCU/WCU are you doing at create time or are you editing it later to add those capacity units? For the GSI, what is its provisioned capacity as compared to the table itself?

Comment: If you are using the same table each time, you would be better of restoring the table using a backup. You wouldn't have to pay for the WCUs to insert the data. https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/backup-restore/

Comment: I am using provisioned. After creation I go to the table and add the auto scaling properties myself. GSI has same provisioned and auto scaling capacity as main table.

Comment: I am using an empty table so a backup is not necessary

Comment: @Stu - So you are probably suggesting that take a backup of the empty table and each time restore that backup when retesting instead of deleting and recreating it again?

Comment: No. I'm suggesting create table, load it, create indexes etc. Then backup. Then test. Then restore to return to pre-test state. This assumes each test starts in the same state.